# Windows Forms and Aero don't mix well -- how do I make them look native?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, aero

It's rather annoying: Windows Forms controls don't look or feel native; they don't glow/fade like they're supposed to.

For example, the top button is not native, but the bottom one is:

[image]

So how do I get this native look/feel in .NET? Is there a way to do it without using an external library?

Comment: I'd never seen anybody use the 'answer your own question' feature, until now. Glad someone is using it.

Comment: @KendallFrey: I guess that means I can later say that I was using it before it was cool. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Just set the *FlatStyle* property on your control to *System*, instead of *Standard*, which is the default.
It's not easy to notice, but it's that easy to fix!

Just be aware that this can subtly affect the control in some situations -- a simple search on `FlatStyle.System` should point you to the caveats.